# POST request works on Postman but does not work in Angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http-post, angular-httpclient

I have a HTTP post request that pings a Django backend. When firing the request from Postman, I am able to get a valid response. However firing from Chrome, with a semantically identical json payload, I receive a 400 bad request.

[Image of the Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0P72F.png)

[Post man example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fSEX.png)

Below is the json model that I'm using the build the body in angular.

The headers remain the same, the authorization is also the exact same (Using basic auth). The only thing I could possibly think would be an issue would be CORS, however, I am proxying it to get around that.

```
export class RealResult {
  node: string;
  source: string;
  destination: string;
  protocol: string;
  source_port: string;
  destination_port: string;
  direction: string;
  acl_ID: string;
  zone: string;
  action: string;
  timestamp: string;
  flowID: string;

  constructor(data: RealResult) {
    this.node = data.node;
    this.source = data.source;
    this.destination = data.destination;
    this.protocol = data.protocol;
    this.source_port = data.source_port;
    this.destination_port = data.destination_port;
    this.direction = data.direction;
    this.acl_ID = data.acl_ID;
    this.zone = data.zone;
    this.action = data.action;
    this.timestamp = data.timestamp;
    this.flowID = data.flowID
  }
}

export class Success {
  results: Result[];

  constructor() {
    this.results = []
  }
}
```

Comment: can you have a look in the network tab of Chrome, to see the real content of the request made by Angular ?

Comment: Absolutely: https://i.imgur.com/sXdrr3M.png

Ran a json-diff: https://i.imgur.com/z9coVMp.png

Comment: Then, talking about CORS, you are proxying angular calls, so I guess you call port 4200. Does port 4200 also work with PostMan, to be sure issue is not comming from proxy ?

Comment: I do indeed call port 4200. I'm not sure how to configure port 4200 in postman though.

Do wanna note: There is a self signed cert in the cert chain. Not sure if that would help anything.

Comment: Well, certificate are bound to a host and port, so that may interfere indeed...

Comment: I'll see if I can talk to the service dev about the cert, but barring that, how would I go about configuring the port on Postman?

Comment: Idk, but it is a must-have for any call, so I would be surprised if postman did not offer the possibility to define a port...